# TypeORM - await queryRunner.query with multiple SQL statements does not work

Tags: typeorm

I am trying to run the following query, as part of a TypeORM migration. It needs to use the inserted_id of the first statement to feed into the subsequent statements. However it does not seem to be working and fails with the error:

**Error during migration run:
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near ";"**

Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
  await queryRunner.query(
  `
      WITH inserted_id AS (
        INSERT INTO "public"."collection" ("created_by", "updated_by")
        VALUES ('system') RETURNING id
      );
      INSERT INTO "public"."metadata" ("name",
                                       "slug",
                                       "description",
                                       "genre_id",
                                       "collection_id",
                                       "splash_src_url",
                                       "logo_src_url",
                                       "video_src_url",
                                       "website_url",
                                       "discord_url",
                                       "telegram_url",
                                       "twitter_url",
                                       "created_by",
                                       "updated_by")
      VALUES ('Githubverse',
          'Githubverse',
          'Githubverse is a game based on Github World, the popular anime franchise with over 60+ million fans.',
          3,
          (select id from inserted_id),
          'https://media.disgaming.com/githubverse/splash.jpg',
          'https://media.disgaming.com/githubverse/logo.png',
          'https://media.disgaming.com/githubverse/video.mp4',
          'https://githubverse.io/',
          'https://discord.gg/githubverse',
          'https://t.me/githubverse',
          'https://twitter.com/githubverse',
          'system',
          'system');
      INSERT INTO "public"."collection_tag_mapping" ("collection_id", "tag_id")
      VALUES ((select id from inserted_id), 3);
      INSERT INTO "public"."collection_tag_mapping" ("collection_id", "tag_id")
      VALUES ((select id from inserted_id), 4);
      INSERT INTO "public"."collection_tag_mapping" ("collection_id", "tag_id")
      VALUES ((select id from inserted_id), 10);
      INSERT INTO "public"."collection_tag_mapping" ("collection_id", "tag_id")
      VALUES ((select id from inserted_id), 19);
  `,
);
```